# How can I pass a filename containing percent signs (%) as a parameter to a shell script in cron?

Tags: cron, quoting

We have currently setup a cron job for our new script as below:

```
46 22 * * * /gzm_common/diagbat9/global/prod/chgstatus.sh /backups/diagbat9/Demantra/output/SK_ITEM_EXTRACT_MFGPRO_$(date +%m%d%y).txt
```

It takes the file with .txt as extension as a parameter. When the cron job executed, the file did not get created. This is what we got of the file at 22:46 pm:

```
22:46    SK_ITEM_EXTRACT_MFGPRO_
```

and this is a zero byte file, whereas it should contain a lot of data.
Shall I try putting the entire filepath and name in double quotes?

Comment: Did you get an emails from cron complaining of errors (and if not, is email properly configured on your box so that you would get them, had it sent any?)

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the percent characters using a backslash:

```
.../SK_ITEM_EXTRACT_MFGPRO_$(date +\%m\%d\%y).txt
```

From the `crontab(5)` man page from the [ISC implementation of `cron`](http://ftp.isc.org/isc/cron/):

> The ``sixth'' field (the rest of the line) specifies the command to be run.  The entire command portion of the line, **up to a newline or % character**, will be executed by `/bin/sh` or
>          by  the  shell  specified in the `SHELL` variable of the crontab file.  Percent-signs (`%`) in the command, **unless escaped with backslash (`\`)**, will be changed into newline characters,
>          and all data after the first % will be sent to the command as standard input. There is no way to split a single command line onto multiple lines, like the shell's trailing "`\`".

Comment: Thank you so very much for your kind and fast replies, really appreciate it. I have done teh change in our crontab and will wait for the results tomorrow. Will let u know how it goes.

Comment: Dear Seniors, it worked, its now funtioning perfectly. Many many thanks for your help!